# getStream plugin not displaying any channels

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, getstream-io, getstream-chat

I'm using the getStream plugin to create a simple-ish android chat app using Jetpack Compose.I have some channels created through the dashboard, but they do not display.

From what I was following (https://getstream.io/chat/compose/tutorial/#displaying-the-channels-screen) there isn't even anything mentioned about creating channels.

Here is what I get when I load the app: [Screenshot of channelsScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOnV5.png)

Here is my code.

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ForumChannelsScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    userData: UserData?,
    context: Context
) {
    // GetStream related code

    // Set-up for OfflinePlugin for offlineStorage
    val offlinePluginFactory = StreamOfflinePluginFactory(
        config = Config(
            backgroundSyncEnabled = true,
            userPresence = true,
            persistenceEnabled = true,
            uploadAttachmentsNetworkType = UploadAttachmentsNetworkType.NOT_ROAMING,
        ),
        appContext = context,
    )

    // Set-up client for API calls and with the plugin for offline storage
    val client = ChatClient.Builder("secret", context)
        .withPlugin(offlinePluginFactory)
        .logLevel(ChatLogLevel.ALL) // would change to nothing if app were to be in production :)
        .build()

    // Authenticate and connect user
    val user = User(
        id = userData!!.userId,
        name = userData.username.toString(),
        image = userData.profilePictureUrl.toString()
    )
    var token = ""
    token = if (userData.userId == "secret") {
        "secret"
    } else {
        "secret"
    }
    client.connectUser(
        user = user,
        token = token
    ).enqueue()

    // Creating a channel
    val channelClient = client.channel(channelType = "messaging", channelId = "general")

    val extraData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>(
        "name" to "Awesome channel about food"
    )
    channelClient.create(memberIds = emptyList(), extraData = extraData).enqueue() { result ->
        if (result.isSuccess) {
            val channel: Channel = result.data()
        } else {
            Log.d("ChannelError", "Something went wrong creating a channel")
        }
    }


    val selectedIndex = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0)}

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
        bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar(
            ) {
                NavigationBarItem(
                    icon = { Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.discover_temp),
                        contentDescription = "Discover"
                    ) },
                    label = { Text(text = "Discover") },
                    onClick = {
                        selectedIndex.value = 0
                        navController.navigate(Screens.DiscoverScreen.route)
                    },
                    selected = (selectedIndex.value == 0),
                    colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults
                        .colors(
                            unselectedIconColor = Orange,
                            indicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(LocalAbsoluteTonalElevation.current)
                        )
                )
                NavigationBarItem(
                    icon = { Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.favorite_unfocused),
                        contentDescription = "Favourites"
                    ) },
                    label = { Text(text = "Favourite") },
                    onClick = {
                        selectedIndex.value = 0
                        navController.navigate(Screens.FavouriteScreen.route)
                    },
                    selected = (selectedIndex.value == 0),
                    colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults
                        .colors(
                            unselectedIconColor = Orange,
                            indicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(LocalAbsoluteTonalElevation.current)
                        )
                )
                NavigationBarItem(
                    icon = { Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.forum_unfocused),
                        contentDescription = "Forum"
                    ) },
                    label = { Text(text = "Forum") },
                    onClick = {
                        selectedIndex.value = 1
                        navController.navigate(Screens.ForumChannelsScreen.route)
                    },
                    selected = (selectedIndex.value == 1),
                    colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults
                        .colors(
                            unselectedIconColor = Orange,
                            indicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(LocalAbsoluteTonalElevation.current) // sets the indicator color to the same as the color of
                            // the navbar by making sure its the same tone. Tones change on elevation,
                            // so I had to set it to the same elevation as the navbar itself
                        )
                )
            }
        }
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Choose a channel",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall,
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
                if(userData?.profilePictureUrl != null) {
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = userData.profilePictureUrl,
                        contentDescription = "Profile Picture",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(50.dp)
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .clickable { navController.navigate(Screens.ProfileScreen.route) },
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    )
                }
            }
            ChatTheme {
                ChannelsScreen(
                    title = "",
                    isShowingSearch = true,
                    onItemClick = { channel ->
                    },
                    onBackPressed = { navController.navigate(Screens.DiscoverScreen.route)}
                )
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general way to create channels can be found [in the documentation](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/android/creating_channels/?language=kotlin&name=compose).

However, in the code snippet you shared you also have a portion that will create a channel:

```kotlin
// Creating a channel
val channelClient = client.channel(channelType = "messaging", channelId = "general")

val extraData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>(
        "name" to "Awesome channel about food"
    )
channelClient.create(memberIds = emptyList(), extraData = extraData).enqueue() { result ->
    if (result.isSuccess) {
        val channel: Channel = result.data()
    } else {
        Log.d("ChannelError", "Something went wrong creating a channel")
    }
}
```

It describes the way to create a channel without members (see the `memberIds` set to `emptyList()`) and the name of `"Awesome channel about food"`.

Let me know if that makes things clear or if there are any errors happening for you. Always happy to help! :)